# Computer Shuts itself down, event log gives no info

Tags: windows-10, cpu, shutdown

This has been a reoccurring problem that has gotten significantly worse recently. The event log doesn't list what caused the shutdown, just says computer shut itself down.

[image]

I opened up the computer afterwards to see if anything is overheating. The only "hot" thing in the computer is the heat sink, but whenever I put fans in front of my computer and take the side case off, it helps/stops it from shutting itself off. Just noticed my graphics card's fans don't spin. They spin weakly for like 2 seconds on and off during boot and then just stay off. Tried moving it to a different slot, didn't help.

Usually when my PC shuts down, it's because I have several things up that use a lot of CPU, plus I run OBS, a streaming software. Could anyone point me in the right direction to diagnose this? I've tried so many different things and just can't figure it out.

Using Windows 10

- Graphics card - AMD Radeon R9 380
- Disk Drive - WDC wd10EZEX-08N2NA0
- Processor - AMD FX 8320 eight cores
- Some Asus motherboard

Comment: "Just noticed my graphics card's fans don't spin" that's a problem for a start.

Comment: Yeah thats a big problem and Im stuck, can't figure out how to get them back on. Tried another slot, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

OBS is a graphics intensive program as it encodes video, which means that your graphics card would heat up even more. Computers usually turn themselves off when they detect a component overheating, which would most likely be your video card as the fans are not spinning. Opening the case and using fans will definitely help, but it will not be a permanent solution.

Because windows does not have any other evidence of a reason for shutdown other than saying it was unexpected, means that it is either a hardware issue or the BIOS shut down the computer.

The graphics card itself may have a loose power connector (two 6-pins I believe) directly to the power supply, or the fans may be dead.

Comment: The fans seem like they work when I turn the computer on, then just stop working. Theres two fans, every now and then one turns on and then off. Both the power connectors are very plugged in, could this be a power supply problem?